# Sax Parser - Catalog Resolver Entity is resolving each and every time while it validating XML

Tags: java, xml, sax, catalog

I got a task to validate xml against dtd and we'll get more than 20k files to validate.

While testing the performance, we have found the below discrepancies

- using catalog resolver, it's taking more than 35s to complete the validation (it resolves for each file)
- when it's turned off/removed, it's barely taking 2s to complete the run.

I have kept the dtd and it's supporting files under resources, created catalogManager.properties file and referred the catalog file.
Is there any way to resolving catalog once and validate all the files?

```
    private List<ValidationResult> validateWithDTDUsingCR(final List<Path> validateFileList) throws IOException { 
        LOGGER.logEvent("validateWithDTDUsingDOM", "File Parsing started : "); 
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        final List<ValidationResult> response = new ArrayList<>(); 
        try { 
        final SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
        factory.setValidating(true);
        final SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        
        parser.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, ""); 
        parser.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
        
        for (Path targetFolderPath : validateFileList) {
            final List<String> exceptions = new LinkedList<>();
            final File localXMLFile = new File(targetFolderPath.toString());
            try {
                parser.parse(new FileInputStream(localXMLFile), new MyHandler());
            } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
                addResponse(response, localXMLFile, exceptions, e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                addResponse(response, localXMLFile, exceptions, e);
            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException exception) {
        LOGGER.logEvent("validateWithDTDUsingDOM", "ERROR Occurred: " + exception);
    }
    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("validateWithDTDUsingDOM Elapsed: " + (stop - start) + " ms");
    return response;
}

final class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    final CatalogResolver catalogResolver = new CatalogResolver();
    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws IOException, SAXException {
        System.out.println("resolve: "+ systemId);
        return catalogResolver.resolveEntity(publicId, systemId);
    }

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("WARNING : " + e);
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("ERROR : " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Far as I recollect catalogue resolver caches the schemas, use the same instance always, you are creating a new MyHandler in the for loop, create it once and reuse it in the loop. Give it a shot.

Comment: Which catalog resolver are you using?

Comment: @MichaelKay - we are using "xml-resolver-1.2.jar"